# I cannot delete any or all contacts with the U1 webinterface

Tags: ubuntu-one, delete, contacts

I'm not able to delete a single contact or all contacts on the Ubuntu One website.

I have a new computer and want to start with an empty address book on Ubuntu One for several reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu One contacts integration in its current form is going away, and doesn't currently work at all well. I'd recommend removing it from the desktop completely until Q (12.10). You can do that by typing the following in a console:

```
sudo apt-get purge '.*couch.*'
```

As to the website issue, I'll have the guys look into it as soon as you [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+filebug?field.title=I%20cannot%20delete%20any%20or%20all%20contacts%20with%20the%20U1%20webinterface). Please reply with the bug number in a comment.