# Why can't I delete my contacts stored in ubuntu one?

Tags: ubuntu-one, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot delete any or all contacts with the U1 webinterface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91004/i-cannot-delete-any-or-all-contacts-with-the-u1-webinterface)

I go to the ubuntone website and select all contacts, then I click on delete. Then I click on the conformation to delete. But nothing happens all contacts are still there!

Comment: Okay, I have the exact same problem, with single or multiple contact deleting...
This makes it a bug, but I'm not entirely sure how to submit bugs for one.ubuntu.com